"Неярко выраженный вкус" и "не ярко выраженный вкус" -- как интонацией выразить разные значения?
На Грамоте: "Правильны оба варианта написания, однако они будут передавать разные значения:
у блюда неярко выраженный вкус = у блюда слабо выраженный вкус;
у блюда не ярко выраженный вкус = у блюда нет ярко выраженного вкуса".
В первом случае с ударением надо произнести слово "неярко", а во втором -- "не"?
